# Enable desktop sync for folders via Box.com API

Tags: synchronization, box-api

Is it possible to programmatically enable Desktop Sync for a folder via the Box.com API?

My Box application creates a folder at the root level upon installation. I'd like to this folder to be available via Desktop Sync for users who are using desktop clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by updating the `sync_state`parameter on a folder, as [documented here](http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-update-information-about-a-folder).

For example, to do this in cURL for folder with ID 123:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/123 \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-d '{"sync_state": "synced"}' \
-x PUT
```